# Class template alias for a function member signature

Tags: c++, templates

How can I shorten the implementation code?

Declaration:

```cpp
    template<typename Type1,
             typename Type2
    >
    struct SomeStuctWithVeryLongName{
        SomeStuctWithVeryLongName foo();
    };
```

Implementation:

```cpp
    template<typename Type1,
             typename Type2
    >
    SomeStuctWithVeryLongName<Type1,Type2>   
             SomeStuctWithVeryLongName<Type1,Type2>::foo(){//...}
```

How I want to write:

```cpp
    template<typename Type1,
             typename Type2,
             typename Struct = SomeStuctWithVeryLongName<Type1,Type2> 
    >
    Struct Struct::foo(){//...}
```

Comment: You can’t put `typename` in front of that return type.